# Easier way to Sum Multiple Criteria with Date Ranges that vary by criteria

Tags: excel, date

First time posting - This one is throwing me...

There is a 'Data Entry' tab with 50 Unique Identifiers listed.

There is a 'Data' tab with each information organized into each column, Unique Identifier in Column A, Date in Column B, value to be summed in Column C etc.

For this example lets say there are only 3 unique identifiers: 1 , 2 , and 3. (listed in range A1:C1 on the 'Data Entry' Tab)

Each with a different date range that I need information summed from 'Data' tab through(also available on 'Data Entry' tab listed in range A2:C2):

```
1: 4/30/20
2: 4/30/20
3: 7/31/20
```

Start Date: 1/1/2020   (listed in cell A4 'Data Entry')
End Date: 12/31/2020 (listed in cell A5 'Data Entry')

If I want to see the total sum for all Unique Identifiers from date range 1/1/2020 - 12/31/2020, but limited to the date ranges noted above for all Unique Identifiers  - what is the easiest way?

All that comes to mind in order to keep it easy to follow is something like this:

Cell A6 equation to solve for Unique Identifier 1:

```
=SUMIFS(DATE RANGE in 'Data' tab,">="&A$4,  DATE RANGE in 'Data' tab,"<="&A$5,  DATE RANGE in 'Data' tab,"<="&HLOOKUP($A$1,$A$1:$C$2,2,FALSE),  UNIQUE IDENTIFIER RANGE in 'Data' tab, A1)
```

So I am looking at the date range to make sure it is in-between the start and end date, AND less than my Through date for my unique identifier, AND of course that I am summing the data tied to my Unique Identifier.

Then I would do the same equation for each Unique Identifier and sum all of them - otherwise I would end up with an equation that is hard to follow.

Each of those criteria ranges and criteria are important to look for in my situation. In this example it might seem pointless, but in my situation I have multiple periods that need to be summed and multiple ranges that need to be summed(start dates and end dates 2017,2018,2019 etc).

Its not that this method won't work, its that I think there has to be an easier way...

Data tab

[image]

Data Entry tab

[image]

Comment: Even if you explain it, this question is unclear. Please, post a data example, your input and expected output. It will help indeed

Comment: I have added screen shots of the Data tab and Data Entry tab to my original post. The only output I am looking for is highlighted in yellow. The actual values I am summing are not 1's. If that were the case, I would just count the number of months - but I think this is easier to see what I am trying to get at - and hopefully make it easier to derive a formula-based solution. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Are your unique identifiers always numbers?

Comment: The Unique Identifiers will actually be 9 numbers with dashes in them, and will look like this: "01-23456-89".

Comment: Just a note, if your id are with dashed, then they are **not** numbers.

Comment: Understood. I should be able to translate any solution derived from this data example to my actual data scenario. I am just looking for an easier and more concise method. Thanks!